# like page from particular region

Tags: facebook-like

My requirment is to increase the facebook likes. but the likes should be from particular area only. not from whole world. is it possible from any apps or paid apps. or paid ads? or buy likes from particular area?

Comment: This is not programming-related at all.

Answer (score 0):

No it isn't possible to get facebook likes from one location only, either programmatically or otherwise. You can pay to have adverts displayed in a specific area (and to specific age ranges etc) but that won't guarantee likes from the same location.

The best way, as ever, is to produce interesting relevant content, that makes people actually want to like you, rather than try to game the system. You will still get the occasional like from the back of beyond, but if your content / product / business is any good, you will soon see local likes appearing.